# watchOS Send Message not getting called

Tags: ios, ios9, watchkit, watchos-2

Hi I'm having an issue with my code it looks like send message isn't getting called for some reason, thanks

```
if ([[WCSession defaultSession] isReachable]) {
    NSLog(@"Initiating WCSession to Read iPhone Data");
    [[WCSession defaultSession] sendMessage:watchData replyHandler:^(NSDictionary *dataFromPhone) {



        NSLog(@"Sending Empty Write Data Array to iPhone...%@", watchData);


    }
                               errorHandler:^(NSError *error) {
                                   // Log error
                                   NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
                               }];

} else {
    //we aren't in range of the phone, they didn't bring it on their run
    NSLog(@"Unable to connect to iPhone");
}
```

Comment: Did you activate the session, and assign a delegate? Also, you realize that "Sending ..." log message won't appear until the reply handler is called?

Answer (score 0):

From what I see this is the code that runs on iOS, which controls whether the Apple Watch is reachable, but you have to remember (if you have not done of course) to enable the session from either device with the following code, so enable the communication system

```
if (WCSession.isSupported()) {
    let session = WCSession.defaultSession()

    session.delegate = self
    session.activateSession()
}
```